# Can asp:DropDownList be a security threat?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, drop-down-menu, postback

This question is about security threat. I wonder at the below usage can DropDownList selected value changed at client side and affect the server side ?

Here the usage (aspx definition)

```
  <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="dropDownListDrawingArtists" CssClass="DropDownArtists"
                runat="server">
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

server side filling

```
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        if (srLang == "tr")
        {
            dropDownListDrawingArtists.Items.Add("Çizen Artist Filtresi: Bütün Çizen Artistler");
        }
        else
        {
            dropDownListDrawingArtists.Items.Add("Drawing Artist Filter: All Drawing Artists");
        }

        DataSet dsDrawingArtists = DbConnection.db_Select_Query("select DrawingArtist,COUNT(PokemonId) as Pokecount from tblPokedex group by DrawingArtist order by Pokecount desc,DrawingArtist asc");

        for (int i = 0; i < dsDrawingArtists.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dropDownListDrawingArtists.Items.Add(dsDrawingArtists.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DrawingArtist"].ToString());
        }

        if (Session["FilterByArtist"] != null)
        {
            dropDownListDrawingArtists.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["FilterByArtist"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

And the final usage at postback

```
    if (dropDownListDrawingArtists.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        srFilterByDrawingArtist = " and DrawingArtist='" + dropDownListDrawingArtists.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        Session["FilterByArtist"] = dropDownListDrawingArtists.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
```

As you can see i am directly using it at the SQL query. I tested myself at google chrome. Changed the values of dropDownListDrawingArtists and done a postback. the value at the server side was not effected. Just to be sure

thanks for answers

asp.net 4.0 C# 4.0

Comment: You are opening yourself up to sql injection. In the very least use parameters. Also, assume that users can and will supply evil data to your page.

Comment: [SqlParameters??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

Comment: `As you can see i am directly using it at the SQL query` You should never be saying that, ever, in any application you write.  Your SQL queries should use parameterized queries to incorporate any data provided through user input.

Comment: Servy i totally know that. but if data can not be altered why bother ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Because you value the safety of your data and don't want to create vulnerabilities through which little bobby tables can destroy your entire database.  Unless of course you don't care about that, in which case why ask in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it is currently possible or not is irrelevant.  You should still be using [parameterized queries](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-use-parameterized-queries-in-ASPNet-174.php) instead of contencating the stgrings.

The reasoning for this is the same as the reasoning that OWASP defines character escaping as "weak" compared to parameterized queries and parameterized stored procedures, and why [white listing is better than blacklisting](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/01/whitelisting_vs.html).

From the [OWASP cheat sheet to Preventing SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3%3a_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input):

> This third technique is to escape user input before putting it in a
>   query. If you are concerned that rewriting your dynamic queries as
>   prepared statements or stored procedures might break your application
>   or adversely affect performance, then this might be the best approach
>   for you. **However, this methodology is frail compared to using
>   parameterized queries** (emphasis mine) and we cannot guarantee it will prevent all SQL
>   Injection in all situations. This technique should only be used, with
>   caution, to retrofit legacy code in a cost effective way. Applications
>   built from scratch, or applications requiring low risk tolerance
>   should be built or re-written using parameterized queries.

The ***reason*** it's frail is that someone is always working on a new way to exploit any potential hole.  What works to prevent tampering today may be circumvented tomorrow.

---

That said, currently, the ViewState protection offers protection for this.  If someone tampers with the list, they will generally get an automatically generated "Invalid Viewstate" error, and the code wont' process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797918.aspx

But don't rely on that behavior. It can be turned off, and I've seen a Jr. Developer turn it off to try to resolve errors.  (Thank goodness for code reviews.)

Comment: i know sql injection but your answer non relevant to my question. ok so it is not possible to alter dropdownlist data ?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing.  I had to verify what I was about to add. - look below the line in the answer.

Comment: `That said, currently, the ViewState protection offers protection for this.` that protection can be turned off though.  I know people sometimes do that when they want to dynamically modify drop downs via javascript to create cascading drop downs.

Comment: now this has a valid point : The reason it's frail is that someone is always working on a new way to exploit any potential hole. What works to prevent tampering today may be circumvented tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you are very much open to SQL injection attacks. One should never use string concatenation to talk to the database. How do you know the user is not using a program to communicate with your site/application? There can be all kinds of manipulations.

If you let a door open, all kinds of things will go through it.

Comment: i know sql injection but your answer non relevant to my question. i am asking dropdownlist here.

Comment: It is relevant, you just don't know that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any time you take user input of any kind and patch it directly into a SQL query, there is a risk.

First of all, you should verify all input that needs to be in a certain format or of several known values.

Second, use SQL query arguments instead of creating your queries as you do.

Comment: i know sql injection but your answer non relevant to my question

Comment: What's wrong with you? It **is** relevant, and for the two reasons I mentioned. First, you must verify all input that needs to be one of several known values (that's any kind of list). Second, you cannot just take values from any source (that includes dropdown list values) and plug them into a SQL query.